# Classic ASP's Application Variables disappearing

Tags: asp-classic

I've got a classical ASP website in which I store some information inside the Application object. These variables seems to disappear every now and then. I am wondering what could be wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application probably got restarted in the meantime, and their is now way to prevent that, you should probably check your web application lifecycle.
what version of IIS are you running ?

Comment: Microsoft-IIS/6.0. The server almost always remain up. The particular website is less frequently used, say 8 hours everyday then not accessed for the next 16 hours.

Comment: read this article about application pool that might help you understand the issue : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/02/07/asp-startup-shutdown-anomalies-on-iis6.aspx

Comment: default setting application recycle every 29h

Comment: As dvhh states your application will get recycled at regular intervals by default, if you store things in your Application object that need to persist then you need to add logic to your code to save/load the values when appropriate